# Sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n/n^2 $

Tags: real-analysis

The exercise is as follows:
Express in terms of *s* the sum of the seris $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n/n^2$ where *s* = $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/n^2$. How would I go about doing this problem? In the question text it also mentions that the calculation would include a proof that the seris is convergent.

I am self-studying and have been trying to solve the problem myself but to no avail. I tried to integrate it from 1 to infinity but that didn't seem to work. The ratio test does not work since the quotient tends to 1. I'm not sure of how to manipulate it either. I think that a telescoping series might be connected to the solution somehow but I haven't found any connections yet.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Write out the first ten or twenty terms of each series. Write out the difference between the two series. See how you can relate that difference to one of the two series.

Comment: $$ \sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n} = \sum_{\begin{subarray}{c} n = 1 \\ n \text{ even} \end{subarray}}^{+\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n} + \sum_{\begin{subarray}{c} n = 1 \\ n \text{ odd} \end{subarray}}^{+\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$. Then,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} &= -\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} - \frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{4^2} - \frac{1}{5^2} + \ldots\\
&= \left(\frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{4^2} + \frac{1}{6^2}\ldots\right) - \left(\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{5^2} + \ldots \right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2^2}\left(\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \ldots \right) - \left(\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{5^2} + \ldots \right)\\
&= \frac{S}{4} - \left(\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \ldots \right) + \left(\frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{4^2} + \frac{1}{6^2} + \ldots \right)\\
&= \frac{S}{4} - S + \frac{S}{4}\\&= -\frac{S}{2}
\end{align*}
Any and all rearrangements are justified by absolute convergence.